# Finding extreme points of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f$ be a function of the form

$$ f(x) = - 2\sqrt{\frac{x a_0}{x b_0 + c_0}} + \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{x a_n}{x b_n + c_n},$$

where $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n > 0$, $N > 0$ is an integer and constant, $x \in [0, x_{\mathrm{max}}]$. Does anyone have a solution or hint to find the extreme points of $f$, i.e., $f_{\max}$, $f_{\min}$?

Comment: Why do you think there shpuld be a general solution for this? Just consider the sum, compute the derivative. Your're getting a polynomial of degree $N-1$. And you even have the square root. Why on earth do you thing a computation is possible? I think bounds are plausible for maxima and minima, but computation is completely hopeless

Comment: @Diesirae92 This is basic single variable derivative and algebra. Very well defined. Are we supposed to present a complete solution for the askers homework? Also not sure why my answer was down voted. Typical irrational behavior on a math site no less.

Comment: If the polinomial has degree bigger then 5 there is no hope you can find roots. Here you even have a square root. Computing places where the derivative is 0 (note that if you have points where the function blows up the maximum and minimum so not exist) is totally hopeless. Provided $x$ lies in the right intervals maybe you can find bounds for $f$

Comment: Maybe tag should be changed to galiou theory?

Comment: @marshalcraft All the things that you have observed should be seen from mine. If $N = 1,2,3$ or something like that, I will not come here and ask this question. For such cases, I myself can easily attain the answer.

Comment: Oh well you did not put a lower bound on $N$ for which the question is obvious Mr. Smarty Pants. Can you explain mathematically just how I'm to infer your level of math education? Or more importantly the point where you fail to have obvious insite of the answe. It's market ably absent from your question and typically a requirement for a question to explain where understanding breaks down. So much so that quite often otherwise reputable qquestions are down voted here.

Comment: Also this site bears the title mathematics, not mathematician or magician or any other hocus-pocus name. As of now I am the only one to present concrete deductive strategy to answering the question while you hide behind a curtain of vague and indirectly implied attacks on ones intelligence. Where you presume knowledge of everything but never give exact statements isolated from the realm of possibility. Do you know the max min for $N=1,2,3$ please present them in your question and edit, as it is directly pertinent to the question. Careful now, do not be lured out from behind your curtain.

Comment: @Hoping_Blessing - extreme points of the function when *which variables are held constant*?